# how to add UDID in new system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, provisioning-profile, udid

Earlier I use to follow below steps to add UDID in my profile using below link.

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-New-Device-to-Your-Apple-Developer-Portal

I have app where I send client the updated provision file after adding UDID that client send to me so that I don't had to ask to come with iPhone at my place.

Now when I login to developer account, I see Add button as disabled.

Is there any way where I can add UDID in my device list without having iPhone with me?

**Note:**

I have filled only 28 UDID and 72 is still pending.

Is it because I added some iPhone through xcode and downloaded new provision profile through xcode only?

***Below you can see the Add button disabled.***

[image]

Comment: It is may be silly to ask, but are you aware of the 100 devices per account limit?

Comment: @sofacoder : I have added 27 till now... it shows 73 still pending... I am not fool to ask such question... Try to login at developer link and see that they have disabled the add button...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the instructions on a web page. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just happened to me.
I just had to reset the device list.

Click on the Get Started button and remove any device you don't use anymore. When you finish, the + button will be enabled again

Answer (score 1):

Apple allows to reset device list once a year when you renew your developer account with apple.
Apple give chance to remove UDID which are not need more.
 So follow reset device steps once and than `+` sign will be enable for add new UDID in your developer account.